# CSS for html in R-markdown

Tags: html, css, r-markdown

I start with R-markdown, I have a question with CSS defining the look and the format of my html document. I want to create a CSS document and personalizing my html document (i'm really new for this).

do you know how should I procede?
do you know some documentation to help me start with?

thank you.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. The best thing to do is search (on here or on google) if other people have the same issue. Since learning a styling language is something many people have done there will be plenty of content. As Xenio said, you can check w3schools.com

Comment: You can read first "R Markdown: the Definitive Guide" https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/. You also will find useful informations in the Appendix B.2 of the blogdown book: https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/
If you want to go further, read the amazing CSS Tricks website https://css-tricks.com/
Learning CSS is really worthwile!
The most comprehensive and up-to-date reference (but rather technical) is the MDN website: https://developer.mozilla.org/
@MartijnVissers w3schools.com should not be recommended here, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com